# Autoscroll div (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 2 div's (left div and right div). They are separated by half. On the right div you can see some pictures and on left side, there are information, which could be longer on some days that's the reason why I want to let it autoscroll to the bottom and back to the top.
I got already a Script but my version is scrolling the whole website.:/

My question: where is my mistake?

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("leftdiv").height() }, 10000);
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 8000);
    },1500);
},1500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4gLts2f0/5/

I found a script which can scroll down.:) But I got still a problem: I do not know how I can let him jump back to the top and repeat the process
https://jsfiddle.net/4gLts2f0/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try  `$("leftdiv").animate({ scrollTop: $("leftdiv").height() }, 10000);`

Comment: In this case he do nothing. :-/

Answer (score 0):

scrollTop is a tricky properties to play with, i personally solved a similar issue calculating the offset from the top of the page with this function:

```
function getDistanceFromTop(element) {
var yPos = -100;

while(element) {
    yPos += (element.offsetTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
}

return yPos;
}
```

after that i suggest try to use the scroll function from the specific target until you reach the specific point.

Comment: If i understood it right, it is only for fixed parts or am i wrong?

Comment: this function calculate the pixel distance form the top of the document, not the page and you can call it after you rendered your element so you get the starting point of you element and then scroll from there.

Comment: But he needs the "var xPos" aswell or? Because he needs to calculate the pixel distance from the top and the distance from the bottom?

Comment: The problem is not the scroll function, my problem is that he wont scroll in the left div. It should just scroll in the left div.